# Audi A4 (B8) safe to drive with vacuum leak?

Tags: audi, a4, vacuum

Have a 2009 Audi A4 which has been running rough with the check engine light on, especially at idle for two days. The dealer described it as a large vacuum leak, and estimated ~$1000 to replace the intake manifold, etc.

Will bring it to an independent mechanic who is usually good, but in the mean time, is it safe to drive the car in this condition?

(There are also apparently unrelated oil leaks coming from the "the front of the engine").

Comment: Is the car stalling under hard braking?

Comment: @Zaid No seems ok while braking.

Comment: Your fuel mileage might be _terrible_, but not going to kill you in the short term.  Why does the manifold need to be replaced?  Crack?  $1000 seems extreme for a vacuum leak, no?

Comment: @JPhi1618 Ok, thanks. I don't have all the details to be honest, but I think the motor? was broken.

Comment: Hmm, ok.  I had a 2010 Tiguan with the 2.0T and had the manifold replaced under warranty because of a bad actuator, so maybe that's part of your issue along with a leak?  You might search for issues with the 2.0T intake manifold - it's a _very_ common problem.

Comment: If it doesn't stall it should be fine, oxygen sensors will take care of it, but it should suck driving.

Comment: Thanks everyone. It actually drives more or less fine at highway speeds. But not taking any extra risks and will wait until I get a second opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its fine if you drive it, but you might want to get it fixed as soon as possible, because it decreases the power of your vehicle and it could possibly harm your engine.

Comment: As a follow up, yes it was fine for a few days to drive. No further problems cropped up, and the mileage didn't seem too far from normal.